# Swift assign function to var cause retain cycle?

Tags: swift2, retain-cycle

I met a similar question in [Swift Memory Management: Storing func in var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112085/swift-memory-management-storing-func-in-var) but that didn't solve my problem.

Here is my class definition:

```
class Test {
    var block: (() -> Int)?

    func returnInt() -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    deinit {
        print("Test deinit")
    }
}
```

I tried two ways to assign value to `block` property and got completely different result. The second approach didn't cause retain circle, which is quite unexpected:

```
var t = Test()
// This will lead to retain cycle
// t.block = t.returnInt 
// I thought this will also lead to retain cycle but actually didn't
t.block = {
    return t.returnInt()
}
t = Test()
```

In my opinion, variable `t` is captured by `block` while `block` is a property of `t`, so can anyone explain why there isn't a retain cycle?

Comment: Interestingly, if you don't reassign `t` to something else and just let it fall out of scope, it does behave like a strong reference cycle unless you include `[unowned t] in` or `[weak t] in`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, all captured variables are captured by reference (in Apple Blocks terminology, all captured local variables are `__block`). So the `t` inside the block is shared with the `t` outside the block; the block does not hold an independent copy of `t`.

Originally, there is a retain cycle in the second case too, as the block holds a reference to this shared copy of `t`, and `t` points to the first `Test` object, and that `Test` object's `block` property points to the block. However, when you re-assign the shared variable `t` (which is visible both inside and outside the block), you break the retain cycle, because `t` no longer points to the first `Test` object.

---

In the first case, the `t` is effectively captured by value, because the `t` is evaluated immediately in the expression `t.returnInt` rather than be captured as a variable in a block. So a reassignment of `t` outside the block later has no effect on the block, and does not break the retain cycle. So you can think of

```
t.block = t.returnInt
```

as kind of like

```
let tmp = t
t.block = {
    return tmp.returnInt()
}
```